# Detecting if emails send by our application is marked as spam

Tags: email, spam-prevention, google-workspace

We are developing an application that will send periodic updates  and notifications to users as email. The user can opt-in and opt-out of this service via a subscribe option. However we are finding that some users are making the email as spam and as a result our account is getting suspended... Is there any way to track if our emails has been marked as Spam by a user, so that we can stop sending emails to them...

We have a GSuite  service and are using Gmail SMTP to send emails

Answer (score 0):

No.

But you can check if your domain is on any blacklist with tools like [mxtoolbox.com](https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx). And contact those blacklists with the question what you could do to be removed from the list.

In order for a mail to be classified as spam it has to fail a multitude of tests maybe your mails have specific words in the title or the senders address is way to weird or the header is getting corrupted in a certain way or and maybe that's your problem: many people are custom filtering your emails as junk/spam.